# Problems assigning string into another string inside IF statement

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-ide

I'm trying to assign one string to another inside a if statement, basically how it works is, when the program starts the String is NULL, when I assign a new value to it on the console, the main string receives the value, and I created a temporary string to receive the value too. If I insert the `temporary_string = main_string` outside the if statement it will receive the main_string, but if I do so inside the if statement it won't work.

```
String wifi_name;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  String last_wifi_name;

  if (Serial.available()){
    wifi_name = Serial.readString();
  }

  wifi_name.trim();

  Serial.print("wifi_name: ");
  Serial.println(wifi_name);

  Serial.print("last_wifi_name: ");
  Serial.println(last_wifi_name);

  if (wifi_name == ""){
    Serial.println("No value");
  }else{
    Serial.println("It enters here");
    last_wifi_name = wifi_name; //This is not working
  }

  delay(2000);
 
}
```

Output:

```
wifi_name: 
last_wifi_name: 
NULL

wifi_name: Trying to assign this
last_wifi_name: 
It enters here
```

The problem is, the last_wifi_name is not being received from the `=`

Comment: you must compare wifi_name vs a string  `if(wifi_name == NULL)` is nonsense. you forgot quotation marks

Comment: I have changed the comparison, but what you mean as quotation marks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `last_wifi_name` is a local variable. You are setting it with

```
last_wifi_name = wifi_name;
```

but at the end of the loop iteration it's destroyed and at the beginning of the next loop iteration a new empty variable is created.